# Forge Viewer rendering pipeline

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In the latest release of `THREE.js`, Mesh can implement following callback in order to hook into the rendering pipeline:

```
this.onBeforeRender = function (renderer, scene, camera ) {
   ..
}
```

Is there any way to achieve a similar logic in the current implementation of the viewer?

Comment: Looking at the available built-in events and exposed callbacks looks like there isn't anything similar - checking with our Engineering to double confirm if that's and case and will get back soon.

Comment: Sounds good - thanks @BryanHuang

Comment: the THREE.js feature `onBeforeRender` is quite interesting as it allows a custom object to easily hook into the rendering pipeline and gives it access to the current renderer, scene and camera, all one needs to be able to achieve advanced customized rendering effects. Would have been an interesting feature if the viewer could perform a check for such a callback on scene entities before rendering them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Engineering just confirmed the closet options we have out of the box the latest Viewer v7 is the OverlayManager - see its doc here:

```
viewer.overlays.addScene(name)
viewer.overlays.addMesh(mesh, name)
```

Which obviously isn't exactly what you are after but we will assess the possibilities of adding these hooks to our future versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking it out, Bryan.

Comment: in v6 we used the impl.renderAfters.add() with sceneAfter. but now in v7 this feature is removed, would it be possible to look into including that or a similar function to the overlay manager in an upcoming release?

Comment: Unfortunately looks like all callback mechanism has been completely removed - will let Engineering know that is good to have that restore back